# SIM7000e what are the two bottom keep out areas

Tags: pcb

What are the two bottom keep out areas shown in  the [docs: 2.4 Footprint recommendation](http://www.shenzhen2u.com/doc/Module/SIM7000C/SIM7000%20Hardware%20Design_V1.01.pdf)  for SIM7000 module? How should I adrress them in the footprint? Screenshot with markers:

[image]

Comment: See page 47 of the datasheet.  Looks like a Cu. KO for some sort of (x-ray or placement) fiducial.  There are two features there that correlate with these KO's.

Comment: Update. Looks like those KO's are so that no (same side) PCB Cu. touches the exposed GND pour on the SIMM chip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are exposed elements in the package that must be kept away from any copper in the same layer.

Most layout tools have Keepout and Restrict layers that are used for similar purposes ([an example in Eagle](http://dangerousprototypes.com/blog/2012/08/08/how-to-eagle-keepout-and-restrict-layers/)). Place a Restrict or Keepout polygon in the component footprint to correspond with those areas. Alternatively (but less advisable as it would require maintenance if anything moves) you can simply draw the Keepout/Restrict polygons on the PCB itself.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like those KO's are so that no (same side) PCB Cu. touches the exposed GND pour on the SIMM chip.  See page 47 of the datasheet.